# Which fields are required to create an event through Social Tables API

Tags: social-tables

I have the following questions that I was not clear on from the API documentation:

- Which fields are required to create an event?
- What does "Invalid field: 0" mean? (this was an error message received when trying to create an event)
- The sample body includes "spaces" as string -- is this the space name or ID? 
  Is this required? If yes, to create a space I need an event ID but to create an event do I need a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks for using our API. It looks like the developer docs on our portal got kind of mangled.  We'll be working on fixing that soon.

In the meantime, let me try to help.

So, the actual required fields for that endpoint are very minimal, here is a small sample post I made for a room here at Social Tables:

```
{
  "name": "Dan's Office Party",
  "category": "Other",
  "spaces": [
    {
      "name": "st test"
    }
  ]
}
```

The key thing here is that spaces is an array, with at least a name property attached.

The error message you referred to is a failing validation check on the type of one of the fields you submitted.

You do need a space to create an event, but as you can see, only the name is absolutely required. However, if you want to do any diagramming with that event, you'll probably want to attach a *venue_id* with one of our floorplan IDs in addition to the *name* property.

I have created an issue to update the mangled doc located at https://developer.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Events/post_4_0_legacyvm3_teams_team_events and will comment here when it is updated.